# ZXingObjc barcode scanner in a tab bar throw errors

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, tabbar

i have a tab bar and navigation controller for my app. whenever i tap the scan tab, it kept throwing me Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on line:

ZXCapture.m

```
[output ZXQT(setDelegate:)ZXAV(setSampleBufferDelegate:)self
```

Here is my code:
tab bar:

```
TestScanViewController *scannerViewController=[[TestScanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestScanViewController" bundle:nil];
navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scannerViewController];
```

in the TestScanViewController.h:

```
@interface TestScanViewController : UIViewController <ZXCaptureDelegate>
@end
```

in the TestScanViewController.m:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "TestScanViewController.h"

@interface TestScanViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) ZXCapture* capture;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* decodedLabel;

@end

@implementation TestScanViewController


#pragma mark - View Controller Methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    if (self.capture == nil) {
        self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
        self.capture.delegate = self;
        self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

        // Use the back camera
        self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;
        self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;;
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.decodedLabel];
    }else{
        [self.capture start];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];
    }

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [self.capture.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [self.capture stop];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (NSString*)displayForResult:(ZXResult*)result {
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scanned!\n\nFormat: %@\n\nContents:\n%@", formatString, result.text];
}

#pragma mark - ZXCaptureDelegate Methods

- (void)captureResult:(ZXCapture*)capture result:(ZXResult*)result {
    if (result) {
        // We got a result. Display information about the result onscreen.
        [self.decodedLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[self displayForResult:result] waitUntilDone:YES];

        // Vibrate
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}

- (void)captureSize:(ZXCapture*)capture width:(NSNumber*)width height:(NSNumber*)height {
}

@end
```

just like the examples codes from github:
https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/blob/master/examples/BarcodeScanner/ViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are targeting iOS version 6 or higher and using ARC, then the cause of the problem is an incomplete migration to ARC in ZXCapture.m.

Look around line 56 for this code:

```
@interface ZXCapture ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t captureQueue;

@end
```

The `assign` is a leftover from before ARC days. It also causes a compiler warning, which was my clue to the solution.
To solve the problem, change the code into:

```
@interface ZXCapture ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t captureQueue;

@end
```